# How to display random demo Google ads for testing

Tags: google-adsense, performance, load-testing, google-publisher-tags

To benchmark an application I want to display ads in Google Publisher Tag (GPT) slots, even if they aren't defined on the publisher end yet.

I have a network id and ad unit ids, but no ads are assigned to them. Are there any 'testing ads' that Google provides I could use?

It's not public and for testing only.

Comment: I've never used GPT before, but the AdSense snippet code can be configured to public service announcement ads on non-public sites.

Comment: thanks - if you add an url to the snippet code and make it an anser i'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

I had suggested in the comments that Google AdSense can show public service ads.  I think they may have removed this option.  However, they support "backup ads".

You can create your own test ad and host it on your site.   Put its URL in in the backup ad field when creating your AdSense ad unit.

[image]

Alternately, they also fill with a solid color for backup which might be good enough for your case.